# Use groupby to create a new dataframe without necessarily applying any calculations to that groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am looking to group this data frame so that price_1 and price_2 are on the same row, then I want use something like reset_index without applying any calculations to the grouped object and create a new dataframe to then add price 1 to price 2.

In my mind i'm trying to do something like sql where I use a subquery to apply my groupby to and then run calculations over that.

In python, the groupbys work in a way that force you to create multiple groups and then piece them back together, but i'm looking to just reduce the larger dataframe down to where item_number, prod_name, and comp are shared and use that new dataframe to then run some calculations on.

Another way to look at this might be to add those columns together within the group by and create a new column that is the total, and then piece it back together somehow.

```
d = {
'item_number':[1234,56789,2468,1234,56789,2468],
'prod_name':['prod_a','prod_b','prod_c','prod_a','prod_b','prod_c'],
'comp':['comp_a','comp_b','comp_c','comp_a','comp_b','comp_c'],
'price_1':[20.00,16.69,36.21,0,0,0],
'price_2':[0,0,0,5,7,3.69]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Desired output:

```
d = {
'item_number':[1234,56789,2468],
'prod_name':['prod_a','prod_b','prod_c'],
'comp':['comp_a','comp_b','comp_c'],
'price_1':[20.00,16.69,36.21,0,0,0],
'price_2':[5,7,3.69]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: Please add your attempts and desired output. Your description is very vague to me.

Comment: @Psidom hope this helps! literally just trying to use groupby to merge rows that have common values into one row so that price_1 and price_2 are next to eachother so that i can do something like df['total'] = df['price_1'] + df['price_2']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this may be what you're looking for:

```
print(df.groupby(['item_number', 'comp'])['price_1', 'price_2'].sum())
```

The output:

```
                      price_1  price_2
item_number comp                    
1234        comp_a    20.00     5.00
2468        comp_c    36.21     3.69
56789       comp_b    16.69     7.00
```

If you want this to be a new data frame and sum the price column values, you can do this:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['item_number', 'comp'])['price_1', 'price_2'].sum()
new_df['total'] = new_df.price_1 + new_df.price_2
print(new_df)
```

The output:

```
                      price_1  price_2  total
item_number comp                           
1234        comp_a    20.00     5.00  25.00
2468        comp_c    36.21     3.69  39.90
56789       comp_b    16.69     7.00  23.69
```

Comment: oh duh cause if theres only 1 value then sum will just return that value? i could also do anything like .max() or whatever

Comment: yes, i was under the impression that using a list outside of the groupby would force it to try and sum those series together rather than a list of columns to sum individually. ie. i tried g.apply(lambda x: x['price_1'] + x['price_2']).reset_index() which i'm not sure even makes sense haha